# Using Regex to extract value from javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

How can I use regex to parse the numeric value `(104)` assigned to `qtyAvail` in the below javascript?

```
<script>
var buyID       = "302";
var qtyAvail    = "104";
var outBehavior = "Default";
if (qtyAvail == "0") {
    if (outBehavior.indexOf("Disallow") != -1) {
        do this
    } else if (outBehavior.indexOf("Allow") != -1) {
        do that
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I couldn't understand your question, can you please make it more clear ?

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this code? It's already stored in its own variable? If you want numeric value just get rid of the quotes

Comment: @Geohut As I added below, this is actually stored as a string in a php variable, and so I am trying to parse the string to save the qtyAvail value as it's own php variable. Regex seems to be the best way to do that with php.

Comment: Preg_match_all('/var\s+qtyAvail\s+=\s+\"(\d+)\";/', $html, $matches); pull out of matches at $matches[1] then intval() it

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a regular expression, you can just use the native parseInt javascript function:

```
parseInt(qtyAvail, 10); // the 2nd argument 10 means use base 10 (decimal, as opposed to hexadecimal or something else)
=> 104
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I'm actually trying to parse this from scraped data which is stored as a string in a php variable. So I'm looking to search through it with php to pull out just that number and store it as it's own php variable. Is there a php function that can do this without using regex?

Comment: I thought this was a javascript question?  If you have the variable in PHP as a string and want it to be accessible to javascript, you should just be able to do:  var qtyAvial = <?= intval($phpStringVar); ?>